# How to fix data too long for column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am building a database for a school project, I made all my columns however I am getting an error.

"ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'stu_first_name' at row 1"

I've done some searching and I see the error is common for varchar, and people say to switch to longtext, however the project says it has to be char.

```
create table students(
    -> stu_id char,
    -> stu_first_name char,
    -> stu_last_name char,
    -> address char,
    -> city char,
    -> state char,
    -> zip char,
    -> major char,
    -> email char,
    -> phone varchar(255)
```

was my code when making the columns.

Comment: You haven't specified a length for your `CHAR` columns so they have a default length of one.

Comment: I was unaware `CHAR` needed lengths specified. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you made your char columns exactly 1 character long.
I'm not sure that would be enough to save a name or address :D

Just add the length to the column type definition like...
`stu_first_name -> char(30)`

Btw varchar would still be a nicer pick, since the values don't get right padded with space to fill the whole appointed column size...
Imagine using up 30 characters every time... Pretty wasteful for a "Rob" or "Hal" or... "Ben"